# How to handle one user's same requests for node express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am maintaining a node server using express.recently, I sometimes got a problem for handling user's bought virtual product when a user request for buying one item twice (click the buy button twice at same time on client and client has no constraint for such a behavior) at same time .the code below shows how to reproduce it:

```
'buyItem': async (req, res, next) => {
  const itemId = req.params.itemId;
  const userId = req.headers['current-user-id'];

  const orderRecord = await Order.find(itemId, userId)//do mongodb search
  if (orderRecord && orderRecord.status === 'paid') {//second request  detect no orderRecord exists beacase first request haven't create order yet
    return res.status(400).json({
      'code': 101,
      'message': 'you have already bought it',
      'result': {}
    })
  }
  // fisrt request goes here
  const orderNew = await Order.create(itemId, userId)//do mongodb create
  await User.deduct(userId, item.price);

}
```

when fist request coming, orderRcord not exists in db, so it will run the code below the if() judgement. when second coming, it still run the code below the if() judgement because fist request haven't create order yet.By the way , I am using node's cluster for multiple cpus.
How can I handle it properly? Thank you for help.

Comment: you probably want to explore rate-limiting

Comment: thank you for reminding me, express-rate-limit + redis can solve my problem